# Powershell adding a variable in hashtable

Tags: powershell

In my code I need to present key values pairs but one of the key values is an array.  I understand in Powershell you create can create an array with a hashtable. What I am struggling with is how I can have inside the hashtable the value of the key be a variable

My original code from python was:

```
data: {"name":"{{name}}","address" : [{"Number":"{{number}}","Road":"{{road}}","City":"{{city}}”}]}
```

A sample of my code is below enter:

```
$number = "10"

$road = "Downing Street"

$city = "London"

$address = @{"Number" = "$number"; "Road" = "$road"; City = "$city"}

$data = @{
    name = $name
    address = $address 
}
```

Here are the output from the Powershell variables

```
PS C:\tmp> $address

Name                           Value                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                        
Number                         10                                                                                           
Road                           Downing Street                                                                               
City                           London



PS C:\tmp> $data = @{
    name = $name
    address = $address 
}

PS C:\tmp> $data

Name                           Value                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                        
name                           prodsql01                                                                                    
address                        {Number, Road, City}
```

In `$data` the address array does not have the values with it.

Can someone please give some advice on this code and what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$data` does have the values, it just doesn't display them (check `$data.address`). What is the desired output format? You could do `$data | ConvertTo-Json` if JSON output is OK.

Answer (score 1):

As other mentionned, the data is there, but is not displayed through the console. 
My suggestion, especially if you are to have multiple records, is to create a PSobject for both the name/address and the Number/city/road

Replacing your `$address` and `$data` assignment lines with theses:

```
$address = New-Object psobject -Property @{"Number" = "$number"; "Road" = "$road"; City = "$city"}
```

and

```
$data = new-object psobject -Property @{name = $name;address = $address}
```

Your output will now look like this.

```
name       address                                       
----       -------                                       
prodsql101 @{Number=10; Road=Downing Street; City=London}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works tho.

```
PS> $data

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           prodsql01
address                        {Number, Road, City}

PS> $data.address

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Number                         10
Road                           Downing Street
City                           London

PS> $data.address.road
Downing Street
```

If you are wanting it to output the values, then you need to consider how you're going to represent it first.

Answer (score 0):

You put them in an array so you just have to reference each one.

Ex.`$address.Road`

```
$number = "10"

$road = "Downing Street"

$city = "London"

$name = "prodsql01"

$address = @{"Number" = "$number"; "Road" = " $road"; City = " $city"} #I added spaces here

$data = @{
    name = $name
    address = $address.Number +  $address.Road + $address.City
}
```